How to model simple mass fraction calculation in Modelica using OOP approach?
I am wanting to program a simple calculation in OMEdit to better understand how write more Object-Oriented code to find the answer (as opposed to using a single Model). The problem I am trying to solve is given the mole fractions yi and the molar mass Mi of the simplified constituents of air, determine the mass fraction wi for each constituent.
Given:
Mole Fractions (yi) and Molar Masses (Mi) of Air:



Constituent
yi
Mi




N2
0.781
28


O2
0.209
32


Ar
0.01
39.9



Mair =  Σ(yi*Mi) 
wi =yi*Mi/Mair
The answers I am expecting are



Constituent
wi




N2
0.754


O2
0.231


Ar
0.014



To model each constituent of the composition, I have
model Constituent
  parameter Real y "molar fraction";
  parameter Real M "molar mass";
  Real M_total;
  Real w "mass fraction";
equation
w = y * M/M_total;
end Constituent;

To model the collection of constituents and calculate, I have
model Composition

  parameter Integer nc =1;
  Constituent[nc] constituents;
  Real M_total;
equation
  M_total = sum(constituents[i].M*constituents[i].y for i in size(constituents));
end Composition;


and then to execute the program I have
model Example_1_1

  Constituent[3] constituents(
  M = {28,32,39.9},
  y = {0.781,0.209,0.01}
  
  );
  
  
  Composition composition(
  nc = 3,
  constituents =constituents);

equation

end Example_1_1;


but it doesn't work

There are some fundamental issues with your approach:

In Constituent you are missing an equation for M_total.
In Composition the constituents should have parameters set
The example is singular due to multiple reasons.

Also I'm not sure if having models for both, Constituent and Composition is the best approach. I would make the Composition a single record as shown below:
record Composition
  parameter Integer n(min=1) "Number of constituents";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.DimensionlessRatio y[n] "molar fraction";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Mass M[n] "molar mass";
  final parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Mass M_total=sum(y.*M);
  final parameter Modelica.Units.SI.DimensionlessRatio w[n]=y.*M/M_total "mass fraction";
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end Composition;

Records come with the limitation, that they cannot have a equation section, but computing final parameters is good enough in this case.
Then the example would be
model Example_1_1

  Composition comp(
    n = 3,
    M = {28,32,39.9},
    y = {0.781,0.209,0.01});

end Example_1_1;

giving your expected result for comp.w (using the correct equation from the code, not the description).

I wouldn't either use models for each constituent, since they are mixed in the same volume. IMHO a process model should represent an actual object (or a part of it), with its corresponding interfaces with other objects, which are modelled using ports.
